# How to refresh the form to its previous non data state once the data has been submitted

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having a form scenario where user select one form from multiple forms and starts to fill it. After filling when he/she clicks on submit button the data will be posted to server and the server after successful operation returns status as OK then i am showing user pop up where user will get confirmation. Now when user clicks on ok button on the pop up, I want to show the user, same form again to fill. For that the form need to be refreshed. How is it done with angularJS. I am developing app in cordova with ionic framework and it has AngularJS in it.

My form div is this:

```
        <form name="fieldForm" method="post" ng-submit="submitFormData($event, htmlValue)">
        <div class="bootstrap" ng-bind-html="htmlValue.Html | unsafe">

        ......form html.......

        </div>
        <div class="padding">
            <button  class="button button-block button-calm">
                Submit
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
                var formId = html.Id;
                var url = base_url+"put/putFormFilledRawData.php";
                var data = $(obj.target).serialize();
                    $http.post(url, data).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        if(data.alert == 'SUCCESS'){
                            var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                                title: 'Confirmation',
                                subTitle: 'Your data has been submitted successfully',
                                scope: $scope,
                                buttons: [
                                    {
                                        text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                                        type: 'button-calm',
                                        onTap: function(e) {
                                            $(this).hide();
                                        }
                                    },
                                ]
                            });
                        }else{
                            var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
                                title: 'Error Report',
                                subTitle: 'Unknown error has been occurred',
                                scope: $scope,
                                buttons: [
                                    {
                                        text: '<b>Ok</b>',
                                        type: 'button-calm',
                                        onTap: function(e) {
                                            $(this).hide();
                                        }
                                    },
                                ]
                            });
                        }
```

Comment: show the form html..

Comment: if you are asking with the intension to resolve as reloading the variable the i would say my forms are dynamic. The whole html need to be reloaded that i am supposed to ask.

Comment: htmlValue.Html contains html code that differs from form to form

Comment: Can you provide your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to reset the form. You can use the reset function via plain javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("form_id").reset();
```

or using jquery like this

```
$('#form_id').trigger("reset");
```

You can call this function in close pop up function of the modal.